# Object is black in 3rd and 4th viewport shading

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I am a newbie to blender so I am sorry in advance if it's something common or just my mistake.

I have this object and the viewport just shows it black. I tried googling this problem but I just couldn't find any working solution. I figured it has to do something with the two black circles that represent the backround?

Thanks in advance!
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this also occur with other scenes? If that's the case it's likely an issue with your graphics driver or unsupported hardware.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you turn down the scene lighting.
It's a wild guess, but I couldn't reproduce your issue in any other way.

[image]

Comment: I guess it really is a hardware problem. I intended on buying a new graphics card anyways. Thanks for you effort!

Comment: @ondraschwarz That's only necessary if your hardware doesn't meet the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for Blender 2.8x. Otherwise it could be as simple as installing a more recent graphics driver version.

Comment: there are no such options in 2.90

Comment: Hi @phil123 :). These options are present through all versions since Blender 2.81.
If you don't have them, make sure you have an official version from Blender.org.

Comment: sorry but they arent for me, although I could download hdri image and add them in the world shader

Comment: Hi @phil :). Not sure about your situation, but feel free to ask a new question. You can link this one to provide context.